# How to quote values using group_concat

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I need to use group_concat to build a list of comma separated values but I need the values to be quoted. How do I do this?

This:

```
425,254,431,53,513,13,1,13
```

Should be converted to:

```
'425','254','431','53','513','13','1','13'
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('''', your_column, '''' ))
```

Comment: If my subquery returns 1,2,3 in first row and 3,4 in second row and 9,2 in third so it is not working can you please provide me something else

Answer (score 60):

Use MySQL string function [QUOTE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_quote).

```
GROUP_CONCAT(QUOTE(`foo`)) `bar`
```

This will handle cases when the string itself contains a quote.

Comment: @OP, Make this as Accepted Answer.

Comment: @itsneo The accepted answer is what helped OP to solve the original problem. It is not necessarily "the best" solution. Use votes to cast your opinion about the best solution to the issue.

Comment: With distinct: `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(QUOTE(\`foo\`)))`

Answer (score 15):

You can quote the elements before applying `GROUP_CONCAT`.

```
SELECT   GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('\'', some_column, '\''))
FROM     some_table
```

Comment: Thanks Max, I was trying to decide who to credit for this. Thaks so much!

Comment: It works for me even on a multi columns concat.

GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('\'',First_Name, ' ', Last_Name, '\'')) as users